# Resetting VueJS Pagination on watch change

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a small VueJS app that pulls in WordPress posts via the API. Everything works great with pagination to load more posts, however I am not too sure how I can reset the entire XHR `getPosts method` when you change the user ID radio field.

When you change the `author ID` currently, it will not reset the results. I believe it should be something in the `watch:` area to destroy the current page - but not too sure. Thanks!

https://codepen.io/sco/pen/aRwwGd

**JS**

```
Vue.component("posts", {
    template: `
    <ul>
        <slot></slot>
    </ul>
    `
});

Vue.component("post", {
    props: ["title", "excerpt", "permalink"],
    template: `
    <li>
        <h3 v-html="title"></h3>
        <div v-if="excerpt" v-html="excerpt"></div>
        <a :href="permalink">Read More</a>
    </li>
    `
});

var App = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        greeting: "Load more Posts Vue + WP REST API",
        page: 0,
        posts: [],
        totalPages: "",
        apiURL: "https://poststatus.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=2",
        isLoading: "",
        show: true,
        authors: [1, 590],
        currentAuthor: ""
    },
    watch: {
        currentAuthor: "fetchData"
    },
    methods: {
        getPosts: function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var self = this;

            self.page++;
            self.isLoading = "is-loading";

            xhr.open(
                "GET",
                self.apiURL + "&page=" + self.page + "&author=" + self.currentAuthor
            );

            xhr.onload = function() {
                self.totalPages = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-WP-TotalPages");

                if (self.page == self.totalPages) {
                    self.show = false;
                }

                var newPosts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                newPosts.forEach(function(element) {
                    self.posts.push(element);
                });
                self.isLoading = null;
                //console.log(self.apiURL + self.page)
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <section id="app" class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="box">
                <template v-for="author in authors">
                    <div class="author-toggle">
                        <input type="radio"
                            :id="author"
                            :value="author"
                            name="author"
                            v-model="currentAuthor">
                        <label :for="author">{{ author }}</label>
                    </div>
                </template><br>
                <h3 v-if="page>0">Showing Page {{page}} of {{totalPages}}</h3>

                <progress v-if="page>0" class="progress" :value="page" :max="totalPages">{{page}}</progress>

                <posts v-if="posts">
                    <post v-for="post in posts" class="post" :id="'post' + post.id" :title="post.title.rendered" :permalink="post.link" :key="post.id">
                    </post>
                </posts>

                <button :class="isLoading + ' ' +'button is-primary'" v-if="show" @click="getPosts(page)">Load Posts</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset `page`, `posts`, and `totalPages` inside the watcher:

```
watch: {
  currentAuthor() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.totalPages = 0;
    this.posts = [];
    this.getPosts();
  }
}
```

[your codepen with required changes](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PyjLZm?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks @tony19 however, if you click author 1, load posts then switch to author 590 the list does not update to show the first set of posts from that author. Is it possible to completely reload the feed so it removes the author 1 posts at the top and only changes the newly selected author?